# Open editor from bash script and cat file to variable not working

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, subshell

Why doesn't this work? There has to be a very simple answer to this.

I have two bash scripts. The first script calls the second which opens an editor on a tmp file, once user quits, cat the file which will be assigned to a variable in the first script.

## test-use-editor

```
#!/bin/bash

test=$(use-editor)

echo $test
```

## use-editor

```
#!/bin/bash

TMP_MSG="/tmp/tmp_msg"
$EDITOR  $TMP_MSG

cat $TMP_MSG
rm $TMP_MSG
```

If I call `use-editor` without assigning and `$()` the editor opens just fine, but if I try to assign it to `$test` it just hangs. The editor does start because I can see it in my processes, but it's in a subshell or something. How can I get it to open within the terminal which called the first script?

Comment: It works for me - I run `./use-editor`, Emacs opens up, I type `abcd`, exit Emacs, I see `abcd` printed

Comment: @ram If you are using a terminal based editor, then `$(use-editor)` may capture the editor UI instead of showing it on screen

Comment: hmm. I had tried adding `./` before and it still wouldn't work. What's strange is if I just hard code `use-editor` into the first script, it works as expected.  @ArkadiuszDrabczyk

Comment: @thatotherguy I'm using neovim, so yes I am. I'm not sure why it works if the exact same code is in one file rather than two though. Any ideas of things I could try to get it to work in a separate script?

Comment: It likely fails when you put `$EDITOR $TMP_MSG` inside the `$(..)` and works when you don't, regardless of the number of files. The hacky workaround would be `$EDITOR $TMP_MSG > /dev/tty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass tty on to use-editor, as thatotherguy suggested.

test-use-editor

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

test=$(./use-editor $(tty))

echo $test
```

use-editor

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

TTY=${1:-/dev/tty}
TMP_MSG="/tmp/tmp_msg"
$EDITOR  $TMP_MSG < $TTY >& $TTY

cat $TMP_MSG
rm $TMP_MSG
```

Comment: Marvelous! Danke schön.